# Image processing issue in Mathematica 11 on Mac

Tags: image-processing, mac-os-x, version-11

```
c = CurrentImage[]
```

returns an image. Now I try:

```
FindFaces[c]
```

it gives:

FindFaces::imginv: Expecting an image or graphics instead of c.

and c becomes empty.

Executing again

```
c = CurrentImage[]
```

gives the cryptic error:

$AbortedGeneral::cdir: Cannot set current directory to ~/.

Things start to spiral down from here, culminating in a hung kernel, then "Licensing problem" (??)

Anyone has an idea what is happening? This issue is reproducible in a new instance of Mathematica 11.

Comment: Your codes runs fine for me running V11 under OSX 10.10.5. Make sure to try it in a fresh kernel and could you provide the details of OS.

Comment: "and c becomes empty." <- Does your kernel crash?  Do the numbers in the cell labels (In[1], In[2], ...) reset to 1?  If yes, that indicates a crash.

Comment: Also try turning off the suggestions bar in Preferences -> Interface and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Trying again with a fresh kernel first gives an under-exposed photo and the message